# Modifying text documents with python

Tags: python, file, text, append

Let's say I had a .txt document with 1,000 names in it.
The document would look like this:

Jon
Jane
Joe
Jack
Jeremy

and, so on.

Now, let's say, I wanted to append "is lame." to each of the names.
So, I'd want the list to look like this:

Jon is lame.
Jane is lame.
Joe is lame.
Jack is lame.
Jeremy is lame.

and, so on.

How would I do this with python from the command line?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you show some effort in your own first attempt, you'll learn more than if you just acquire the answer here. Try it out and post some code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.

In a nutshell:

```
f = open('my_names_file.txt')
data = f.read()
f.close()
output = ""
for name in data.split(' '):       # This assumes each name is separated 
    output += name + " is lame. "  # by a space and no name contains a space
print output
```

It's just as easy to write the output back into a file.  It's explained well in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
print ' '.join(i + ' is lame.' for i in open(fname).read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly python specific, but you get the idea....

```
In a loop parsing each token (name):
1.  Get the name into a string
2.  Append "is lame" or whatever else to the string
3.  Append that string onto a buffer
```

After the loop is over, replace your document with the new buffer.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. I can do the actual append part of the code, "for name in names" and such. What I meant was, how to actually import the original names in the text document so I can modify them. Do I need  to use the import function?

Comment: sorry, dont know much python.
Im sure you can find something on python file i/o with google

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s="Jon Jane Joe Jack Jeremy "
>>> s.replace(" ", " is lame. ")
'Jon is lame. Jane is lame. Joe is lame. Jack is lame. Jeremy is lame. '
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a very basic sample:

```
outputLines = []
with open('c:\\file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            outputLines.append(' is lame. '.join(line.strip().split()))
with open('c:\\file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in outputLines:
        f.write(line+'\n')
```